# Why does Apple Mail signatures automatically uses custom signature with all added mailboxes, instead of one?

Tags: apple-mail

I've added a signature through Mail->Preferences->Signatures.

Apple Mail now automatically adds the signature in all my e-mails with all three accounts (hotmail, google, work) when I try to send something. I just want the signature when I sent work e-mail. How do I edit this?